# Value of variable expected_yield doesn't show

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

```
echo "Calculate Expected Yield"
read -p "Enter water applied (in inches): "water_applied
read -p "Enter crop area (in acres): "crop_area
read -p "Enter WUE value: "selected_crop_WUE
expected_yield=""
expected_yield=$(echo "scale=2; $water_applied * ($selected_crop_WUE / 100) * $crop_area" | bc)
echo "Expected yield: $expected_yield kg/acre"
```

I tried to check if `bc` is downloaded properly and tried using awk too, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You missed spaces before each variables at the end of each `read` commands, so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Calculate Expected Yield"
read -p "Enter water applied (in inches): " water_applied
read -p "Enter crop area (in acres): " crop_area
read -p "Enter WUE value: " selected_crop_WUE
expected_yield=""
expected_yield=$(echo "scale=2; $water_applied * ($selected_crop_WUE / 100) * $crop_area" | bc)
echo "Expected yield: $expected_yield kg/acre"
```

And no need `expected_yield=""`: you can remove this line

Comment: `read` would not complain about this: the variable names are just concatenated with the prompt, and read uses its default variable `$REPLY`